# Activity with theme Dialog's custom title height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-styles

I have an activity with the following theme

```
<style name="CustomDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/PauseDialogTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PauseDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:height">70dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle</item>
    </style>
```

and this is the custom title layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/first_line_title_text"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="first line" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/second_line_title_text"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="second line" />
```

I can only see one line of the title layout
What's causing the title to show only one line with fixed height ?
although i'm specifying height in the layout and style